# How to create real function in Bigquery Legacy SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, user-defined-functions

I know UDF in legacy sql, but UDF need you pass whole row into function, and return whole record, and UDF can't put into select section, this is not real function I need, Is Bigquery Legacy SQL can write function like Standard SQL? (can put into select or where section)

thanks :)

Comment: Why do you want to use legacy SQL? The BigQuery team is adding new features only to standard SQL at this point, so that's what I would recommend to use.

Comment: Thank you suggestion, in fact I am not sure legacy sql can't create function, so I post this question, but now I think standard sql is the only choose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This functionality is only supported in Standard SQL (and as Elliott mentions in the comments, is unlikely to be added to Legacy SQL because it is being phased out).